# Roblox-How to fix tool manager

Tags: roblox

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")

local remotes = ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("Remotes")
local tools = ServerStorage:FindFirstChild("Tools")
local scripts = ServerStorage:FindFirstChild("Scripts")
local toolConfig = require(ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("Config"):FindFirstChild("ToolConfig"))

remotes.ToolActivated.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player: Player)
    local playerTool = player.inventory.EquippedTool.Value
    for tool, toolTable in pairs(toolConfig) do
        if tool == playerTool then
            player.leaderstats.Decibel.Value += toolTable.Decibel
        end
    end
    print(player.Name)
end)

for _, tool in ipairs(tools:GetChildren()) do
    local script = scripts.Click:Clone()
    script.Parent = tool
end
```

This is my code to make the Decibel Value from leaderstats go up
Then It doesn't show any error up but it isn't working.
It doesn't print the player name and also it doesn't make the Decibel Value go up
help

Comment: Do you have any code that is firing `remotes.ToolActivated:FireServer()`?

Comment: I think I had it before but I can't find it now

Comment: only I have is `finished:Fire()`

Comment: Is there any problem in this script? `local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local remotes = ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("Remotes")

local tool = script.Parent

tool.Activated:Connect(function()
 print("LOL")
 end)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client, you need to fire the signal.

```lua
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local remotes = ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("Remotes")
local tool = script.Parent
tool.Activated:Connect(function()
    remotes.ToolActivated:Fire()
end
```